# How to check if Hibernate session is still valid after possible corruption

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using long sessions (conversations) spanning several web requests with Hibernate, where a global interceptor manages opening and closing Hibernate sessions. If a session crashes with a `HibernateException` (e.g. a `ConstraintViolationException`),  it [cannot be used any more](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) because of danger of unpredictable behavior. So the session must be closed and discarded, and a new one opened. However in my design, session management (web request interceptor) and data access code are at different layers, so the interceptor cannot know at the end of request if a `HibernateException` has occurred in the middle or not. I need some way to test if the session is still valid and if it can be continued to use. Using `session.isOpen()` won't help: even if returns `true`, further calling methods on the session may cause another crash.

Is there any reliable way to do that? Thanks!